# Fixed header in Excel using JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

How can I create an excel report with fixed header using JapserReports?
I mean that I need the header to be fixed when I scroll the Excel file.

Comment: Will you always know the max number of columns for the fixed header or will you use the same template for different reports with their own fixed header?

Comment: I always know the max number of columns, and I have two separate templates that need this functionality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is currently possible by adding a couple properties in the jrxml file for each report. Take a look at [Advanced Excel Features](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsfeatures/) for Freeze Panes. If you wanted to freeze everything after your first column header (down the left side basically) it would look like this:

```
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Sans_Bold" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="60" width="104" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#666666">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.filter" value="Start"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.column.width" value="110"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.freeze.column.edge" value="Left"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[State]]></text>
            </staticText>
```

or if you wanted to freeze everything below your header you could do something like this below own of your fields:

```
           <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Sans_Bold" mode="Opaque" x="316" y="60" width="199" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#666666">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.freeze.row.edge" value="Bottom"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Street]]></text>
            </staticText>
```

If you download the JasperReports zip, there is a demo folder in it, that contains this working example, in the xlsfeatures folder. As a final not, the demo worked for me when exporting to xls, but not when I tried to use xlsx (although there may be a way to make it work, I could not find anything quickly).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Jaspersoft Studio, this can be achieved by right clicking on an element and select **XLS Tags**

[image: Set Image XLS Element]